# Sylius Vagrant Installation error about rsync on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, sylius

During installation of the vagrant version on Winwows 10 I got the following error:

There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /c/Users/Gunnar/Development/Vagrant-master/
Guest path: /vagrant
Command: "rsync" "--verbose" "--archive" "--delete" "-z" "--copy-links" "--chmod         =ugo=rwX" "--no-perms" "--no-owner" "--no-group" "--rsync-path" "sudo rsync" "-e         " "ssh -p 2222 -o LogLevel=FATAL   -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyCheckin         g=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i 'C:/Users/Gunnar/Development/Vagrant-mas         ter/.vagrant/machines/sylius/virtualbox/private_key'" "--exclude" ".vagrant/" "/         c/Users/Gunnar/Development/Vagrant-master/" "vagrant@127.0.0.1:/vagrant"
Error: This rsync lacks old-style --compress due to its external zlib.  Try -zz.
Continuing without compression.

Do you know how to solve it?
Where to change the rsync settings?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to Vagrant 1.9.6 from 2.0. Then the error did not appear. Now I got another error.